# Generating Laguerre polynomials using gamma functions

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, gamma-function, contour-integration, residue-calculus

An exercise given by my complex analysis assistant goes as follows:

> For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x>0$ we define
>   $$P_n(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_\Sigma \frac{\Gamma(t-n)}{\Gamma(t+1)^2}x^tdt$$
>   where $\Sigma$ is a closed contour in the $t$-plane that encircles the points $0,1, \dots, n$ once in the positive region.

Now, we have to prove some things like that $P_n(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, which is no problem. However, the assistant claims that $P_n(x)$ "is known as a Laguerre polynomial". However, calculating $P_n(x)$ for certain $n$ and comparing to values of the Laguerre polynomials $L_n(x)$ on the internet, I find that 
$$(-1)^n \cdot n! \cdot P_n(x) = L_n(x)$$
Could my assistant have made a typo which explains this missing factor; or could he mean that $P_n(x)$ have similar properties as the Laguerre polynomials, perhaps?

Comment: I know that, Legendre polynomials have the property $ L_n(-x)=(-1)^n L_n(x)$. So, you can check if Laguerre polynomials have the same property.

Comment: Legendre polynomials have this property because, if $n$ is even/odd, then all powers of $x$ are even/odd. Laguerre polynomials of degree $n$ have terms with every power of $x$ (being $0, 1, \dots, n$) so this property doesn't hold, unfortunately.

Comment: How did you manage to prove that it is a polynomial of degree $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to multiply the integral representation by $(-1)^n n!$, so you will have the right integral representation

$$ P_n(x) = \frac{(-1)^nn!}{2\pi i} \oint_\Sigma \frac{\Gamma(t-n)}{\Gamma(t+1)^2}x^tdt. $$

For instance,

$$ P_5(x) = 1-5\,x+5\,{x}^{2}-\frac{5}{3}\,{x}^{3}+{\frac {5}{24}}\,{x}^{4}-{\frac {1}{120
}}\,{x}^{5},$$

which agrees with the [Laguerre polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials) $L_5(x)$.